# Really disable XML Schema Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vmware

The first time you open up an XML file in a Visual Studio 2008 SP1 instance, it opens up XML schema explorer. I want to disable it. Is this possible?

Background: I'm developing within a VMware environment (yes, I agree, that *is* the real problem here). XML Schema Explorer uses graphics acceleration, and this messes up the VM (it drops out of full-screen mode, flashes, and sometimes freezes). I [could](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/185219) disable the graphics acceleration in the VM, but that would stop me sharing the cursor with the host machine, and I'd rather retain that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has two separate threads, both answered, at least in part:

[How do I turn off XML Schema Explorer?](https://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=How+do+I+turn+off+XML+Schema+Explorer%3f&d=5005196329889289&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=Y8LHZhBAgRvkGfDfBYBbquf00CL4mfLQ)
This link suggested resetting **ALL** dev environment settings.

`devenv /ResetSettings`

the userdata

`devenv.exe /resetuserdata`

and the Windows Layout. The reporting user replied that window locations did not appear to be the issue, however they reported temporarily solving the problem themselves by:

> I click on the "pushpin" on the window, and then slide it open, and then click the X button, and restart VS2008, the window goes away.

They also state that they had no luck with assigning the XSD file extension to XML Editor.

[How can I keep XML Schema Explorer from opening by default?](https://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=How+can+I+keep+XML+Schema+Explorer+from+opening+by+default%3f&d=4941085347301009&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=sLyk8NFHgCHG8kk4hpFcO4QlfxtEKoIV)

Which called out that the tool "is hidden by default". It encouraged the user to quote:

1. Click the Tools menu in Visual Studio and choose Import and Export Settings.
2. Choose Reset all settings radio button and click Next button
3. Back up the current settings if you like and then click Next button
4. Choose settings, C# development settings or Web Development settings and click Finish button

unquote.

Note: Those steps will reset ALL your settings. Also, the commenters did not see success.

hopefully one of the two above will solve your issue.

I suggest remapping the file extension to some non-XML editing experience, text, as a first attempt.

Comment: @Jivlain Thank you for updating the links.  Did either of them address your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't actually had a moment in which to test this - I've left that job and no longer even use Visual Studio at work, and have taken to spending my weekends on an island with no electricity. I'll try to get at that as soon as I can.

Comment: Both of these links are dead.

Comment: @MyCodeMadeMeSuicidal thank you!  I'd like to claim I was young and hadn't realized the dangers of Link Only Answers yet... hopefully the update helps.